# How can I list all user names on Solaris 10?

Tags: users, solaris

I forgot a user that I  created  on solaris 10, so now **I would like to list all user names on my server**.

Is it possible (I am root user)? What command I should use if possible?

Somewhere on the net I read `getent` will list all usernames of a group. I have tried ***getent*** without a group as I do not remember group also, but got error message (getent databse usage ..)

Comment: Show the code that you tried and the error message that you got!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getent passwd` will list all known users, not only those present on the local `/etc/passwd` file.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason why you cannot use the passwd database?

```
awk -F':' '{ print $1 }' /etc/passwd
```

From the perspective of a group, users are usually listed as part of the group in the /etc/group database:

> plugdev:x:46:someusername

Comment: Unless you are on a standalone machine, the password database is not necessarily limited to the accounts stored in the /etc/passwd file. There are other common sources for user accounts, especially NIS and LDAP, the reason why getent is to be preferred.

Comment: @jlliagre - Very true. I took from the OP that getent had already been tried. Additionally my interpretation of the phrase "created on solaris 10" lead me to believe that the user was local, which may be incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `dispuid` command. From the `man` page:

```
NAME  
    dispuid - displays a list of all valid user names

DESCRIPTION  
     dispuid displays a list of all user names on the system (one
     line per name).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F':' '{ print $1 ,  $2 }' /etc/shadow | egrep -v "NP|LK"
```

will print accounts from shadow file that are not locked or have no password - so the rest is active accounts with passwors set - I guess that is what you are after ?